# Can't Update Python

Tags: linux, python

I have Python installed at `/usr/bin/` and its version is 2.6.
Then I downloaded Python2.7.tgz and extracted it at location /scratch/bin/ and then installed using the steps

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After Installing when  I type:

```
Python - V 

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 20 2012, 15:53:42) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Thus I am getting older version only

Also i don't have read and write access inside `/usr/` folder

If I do `type python` I get back `python is hashed (usr/bin/python)`.

Comment: did you run `sudo` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried everything

Comment: Please edit your question and specify the Linux distribution you are running and what did you try with the resulting messaging errors, otherwise no one can answer your question. The only command you showed us is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: What is the output of `type python`?

Comment: python is hashed (usr/bin/python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing python use the following steps
using prefix to specify the installation directory

```
 ./configure --prefix=/scratch/bin/
 make
 make install
```

Then everytime u run a new Terminal u have specify

```
export PATH="$PATH:/scratch/bin/"
```

to tell where is the installation directory of Python

Comment: You can add `export PATH...` to your ~/.bashrc to save you having to run it every time.

Comment: *Surely* you mean `--prefix=/scratch/bin/` without the spaces? Because otherwise this doesn't make sense, and is likely to have the configure script fail because of unknown parameters.

Comment: Sorry for the spaces